# How to insert alternating spaces in an alphabetic string?

Tags: google-sheets

If the formula:

```
=REGEXREPLACE("" & A1, "(\d)", "$1 ")
```

separates a number string with spaces (Ex.: 1234 => 1 2 3 4), how can I change it to do the same to letters (Ex.: ABCD => a b c d)?

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=REGEXREPLACE("" & A1, "([[:alpha:]])", "$1 ")
```

Other options (many!) here: [how to use RE2 expressions.](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt)

This separates with spaces but does not change case (for which there is [LOWER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094083)).

The above has this effect on `abdc 1234`:

```
a b d c  1234
```

For this effect `a b d c  1 2 3 4` on `ABcD 1234` try:

```
=lower(REGEXREPLACE("" & A5, "([[:alpha:]]|[\d])", "$1 "))
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems my other offer did not suit, so trying again with something more like OP's version:

```
=lower(REGEXREPLACE("" & A1, "(\D)", "$1 "))
```